# VB.net 2013 - Nested loop triangle

Tags: vb.net, loops, nested

Im trying to set up a nested for loop to produce the following output using VB.net:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

How would you solve this? I've been going at it for a while but i just cant get it right..

Comment: If you show the attempt you have made by including your code, we can improve upon it and explain the changes. That way we know what you already know, and can just cover the missing pieces.

Comment: You should atleast attempt to do your homework... Try to understand the logic, try to do it. Show us your attempt.

Answer (score 2):

```
  TextBox1.Multiline = True
  For k As Integer = 1 To 10
        For i As Integer = 1 To k
            TextBox1.AppendText(i.ToString & " ")
        Next
        TextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
  Next
```

Comment: Ahh...No. It will work with one line as well, you just won't be able to see the seperated lines...Any way, why do you think he want's a label and not a text box ?

Comment: @  Eminem : hope that you put -1 for me. i just edited the code now it will work fine so +1 for you

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim i, j As Integer
 Label1.Text = ""
 For i = 1 To 10
     For j = 1 To i
         Label1.Text &= j & " "
     Next
     Label1.Text &= vbNewLine
 Next
```